# Set PK from ManyToMany annotations in Doctrine2 entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've a ManyToMany relationship between `Pais` and `FabricanteDistribuidor` tables defined as follow:

**Pais.php**

```
class Pais
{
    // column definitions

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\FabricanteDistribuidor", inversedBy="paises", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="negocio.fabricante_distribuidor_pais", schema="negocio",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="fabricante_distribuidor_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="pais_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $fabricanteDistribuidor;

    /**
     * Add fabricanteDistribuidor
     *
     * @param AppBundle\Entity\FabricanteDistribuidor $fabricanteDistribuidor
     */
    public function addfabricanteDistribuidor(\AppBundle\Entity\FabricanteDistribuidor $fabricanteDistribuidor)
    {
        $this->fabricanteDistribuidor[] = $fabricanteDistribuidor;
    }

    /**
     * Get fabricanteDistribuidor
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getfabricanteDistribuidor()
    {
        return $this->fabricanteDistribuidor;
    }
}
```

**FabricanteDistribuidor.php**

```
class FabricanteDistribuidor
{
    // column definitions

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Pais", mappedBy="fabricanteDistribuidor", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $paises;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->paises = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Set paises
     *
     * @param  AppBundle\Entity\Pais $pais
     * @return FabricanteDistribuidor
     */
    public function addPaises(\AppBundle\Entity\Pais $pais)
    {
        $this->paises[] = $pais;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get paises
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getPaises()
    {
        return $this->paises;
    }
}
```

That will generate a table `fabricante_distribuidor_pais` on the schema `negocio` with `fabricante_distribuidor_id` and `pais_id` FK pointing to the PK on the related tables, that's fine.

Regarding this scenario:

1- It's possible to define `fabricante_distribuidor_id` and `pais_id` as PK on the `fabricante_distribuidor_pais` table? I mean adding some extra annotation or I need to create a external entity and set them as `@ORM\Id` on the column definition?

2- Are the `addXXX` and `getXXX` methods right in my entities? By right I mean: I should add one or many `paises` (from Pais entity) to `FabricanteDistribuidor` easily and I don't care about to the inverse relation meaning I will not add `FabricanteDistribuidor` from a `Pais`, are them right or do I need to change something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- If one id is a primary key doesn't the relation becomes many to one/ one to many ? Even 1to1 if both are PK 
 
2- If you don't care about the inverse you are going to add getters and setters in only one entity yes. You can still change it to a biredictionnal later with the attribute "mappedBy"

---

Check if an entity exists :

You can do that in your controller :

for example in Pays

```
$data = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Pais')->findOneByFabricanteDistribuidor($id);
if($data)
{
    // the entity is allready persisted 
}
else
{
    // no, we can persist the entity
}
```

Comment: you're right! Now having the same info how do I check, for example if a records already exists on `fabricante_distribuidor_pais` for avoid then the non duplicates error if I try to insert the same, any advice on this one?

Comment: if you're building a one to many or many to one relationship this intermediate table won't exist. Anyway in all cases you can do what i wrote in my edit

Comment: I'm trying check the existence of a given row formed by both keys and I'm getting this error `Notice: Undefined index: joinColumns in /var/www/html/project.dev/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1665` any advice?

Comment: Detail more, or submit a new question :)

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975636/check-if-unique-row-already-exists-using-findby-in-manytomany-any-workaround-or)