# Check if UNIQUE row already exists using findBy in ManyToMany, any workaround or working solution?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, many-to-many

So I've this relations defined in my entities:

```
class Producto
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Norma", inversedBy="normasProducto", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="nomencladores.norma_producto", schema="nomencladores",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="producto_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="norma_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $productoNormas;

} 


class Norma
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Producto", mappedBy="productoNormas", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $normasProducto;
}
```

And I'm trying to check if a given pair `producto_id`-`norma_id` already exists for not try to insert it once again and I'm doing as follow:

```
$exists = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Producto')->findOneByProductoNormas($productoId);

if ($exists) {
    $status = 400;
} else {
    try {
        $producto->addProductoNormas($normaEntity);
        $em->flush();
        $response['success'] = true;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $status = 400;
        $response['error'] = $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: joinColumns in
>   /var/www/html/project.dev/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php
>   line 1665

Doing a research on Google and here on SO I found that possible it's a bug as point [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2988) or perhaps is not and we (me and the others who report the issue) are doing something wrong. I can't find where the issue or problem is so any advice or help will be fine for me and others. The only idea I have in mind is create a view at RDBMS and then create a entity for read it and check if record already exists, I have not other than this one, any ideas? Help? Working example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can use 'database_connection' service to check if such row exists:

```
$this->get('database_connection')
     ->fetchColumn('select count(id) as cnt 
                    from <norma_producto_table> 
                    where producto_id = ? and 
                          norma_id = ?', array($producto_id, $norma_id));
```

That's really easier than trying to handle this with many to many relations methods. I would do that if I had to do what you need (and actually I'm doing so).

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer because it is against the purpose of databse abstraction. If he want's to use raw SQL, he could simply use INSERT IGNORE. But it does not update collections and is bad practice when there are better solutions.

Comment: And what is the better solution in this case? He wants to check if such row exists. Doing

    $producto->getNormas()->contains($norma)

look worse and really ugly. The way I suggested is not the best, it's alternative way and it solves the issue. And the is nothing bad in using SQL, in some cases it's easiest way to do simple things. And I think INSERT IGNORE is not what the author of this request really wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the definitive answer but i had the same problem and it had something to do with my entities annotations can't tell you exactly what though..

Here is a working example with photos and albums

```
class Photo
    {
         /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Album", inversedBy="photos")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
        */
        private $albums;

class Album
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Photo", mappedBy="albums")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
        */
        private $photos;
```

In order to check the existence you could do, let's say you're searching for an idPic photo

```
$photo = $repository ... ->findOneBy($idPic)
if($photo->getAlbums()->contains($album))
```

Comment: This solution is not working for me, still can add the same records and therefore keep getting the same error related to duplicates `Unique violation: 7 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "norma_producto_pkey"`

Comment: This is the right solution. But `contains` does not look for IDs, but for the elemnt itself. So it should be `->contains($album)`!